# How to connect two VPCs which have the same CIDR Blocks in the same account but two different regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering

I have a VPC in region A which holds the RDS Aurora Instance and a VPC in region B which holds an EC2 instance. Currently the EC2 instance connected to the RDS instance by allowing all the MYSQL connections in the Security Group of the RDS, but since this is not best practice , I am trying to create a VPC Peering Connection.

The problem is both VPCs share the same CIDR Blocks and each VPC has its own resources, so it will be difficult to create a new VPC and migrate the resources from the old VPC to the new VPC. Is there a way to connect the two VPCs or update the CIDR Block in one of the VPCs ?

Comment: You probably need to use AWS Transit Gateway https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/

Comment: NAT, then VPN or TGW.

Answer (score 2):

Because they have the same CIDR range, routing would never know where to route an address so this cannot be done.